# Google adwords conversions on website

Tags: web, tracking, google-ads-api

I have website and on it I have booking form. When you complete booking form fields you click proceed and go to third-party site that makes transaction and then you are redirected to /success page. 
I have one account where I have set Google adwords campaign and another where I want to track conversions. I made conversion and set it with no value, just to record it. I put code of conversion in top of my /booking page.

```
<!-- Google Code for Tracking conversion Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 947106710;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "scPuCPe3ql4QlufOwwM";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/947106710/?label=scPuCPe3ql4QlufOwwM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

But I do not see any conversions.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set conversions on the account where is your ad campaign.